# Where is kmalloc()-contiguous memory allocation required other than DMA?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

What are the cases where a `kmalloc()` is required other than the DMA memory allocation. Where else it could be used (the other places where in a **contiguous memory allocation** is required)? To be precise , I need to know some places where in only `kmalloc()` can be used and not `vmalloc()`. I know DMA is one example of this kind, what are others?

Comment: `kmalloc` is used for **almost every allocation** for in-kernel use. In some sense, `kmalloc` in kernel corresponds to `malloc` in user-space applications. Probably, you mean some other function? E.g. `vmalloc`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I would like to know few examples where a contiguous memory allocation is needed in kernel. I know DMA functioning and that is an example. I would like to know some other cases other than DMA.

Comment: What do you mean? Everywhere where you need memory for data types (structures, buffers of data, etc).

Comment: I need to know some use cases of kmalloc()-a [contiguous memory allocation] where in vmalloc() cannot be used. I know one use case is DMA memory allocation, what are the others? I edited my question if there it is not clear.